# How to animate the closing of a custom sidebar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a custom sidebar component in react. Though I can animate its opening but can't animate the closing. I do understand the reason why it doesn't animate on closing but I am not being able to find a way to fix it. I also would like the sidebar to be removed from dom when collapsed.

**Header.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showSidePanel: false,
        isSignUp: false,
        isLogIn: false,
    }
}
.
.
.
closePanel = () => {
    this.setState({
        showSidePanel: false,
        isSignUp: false,
        isLogIn: false,
    })
};
.
.
.
<Button
    text="Log in"
    onClick={ () =>
        this.setState({
            showSidePanel: true,
            isLogIn: true,
        })
   }
/>

<SidePanel open={ this.state.showSidePanel } onClose={ this.closePanel } />
```

**SidePanel.js**

```
class SidePanel extends Component {
    render() {
        const { open, onClose } = this.props;
        let slideDirection = open ? "slideInRight" : "slideOutRight";

        return (
            open ? (
                <div className="pageOverlay right" onClick={ onClose }>
                    <div className={`panelWrapper animated faster ${ slideDirection }`}>
                        <p onClick={ onClose }>Close Panel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null
        )
    }
}

export default SidePanel;
```

Comment: Consider using ReactCSSTransition group for animation.
[Here is a nice article with example][1]

and

[Reactjs documentation ReactCSSTransitionGroup][2]


  [1]: https://blog.prototypr.io/using-reactcsstransitiongroup-for-enter-exit-animations-ea100d68e72f
  [2]: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Comment: @Shahram alright. I proceeded with the references you provided and got it done but I faced another issue. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53674024/3697102